# Remove parenthesis and contents in parenthesis if present in a df column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the top scores/instances have parenthesis. I would like to remove the parenthesis and only leave the number. How would I do so?

I have tried the code below, but it leaves me with nans for all other numbers that do not have paranthesis.

```
.str.replace(r"\(.*\)","")
```

This is what the columns look like:

```
0    1(1P)
1    3(3P)
2    2(2P)
3    4(RU)
4    5(RU)
5    6(RU)
6        8
7        7
8       11
9       13
```

I want clean columns with only numbers.

Thanks!

Comment: Alternative - `df['a'].astype(str).str.findall('\d+').str[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is mixed values - numeric with strings, possible solution is:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(str).str.replace(r"\(.*\)","").astype(int)
print (df)
    a
0   1
1   3
2   2
3   4
4   5
5   6
6   8
7   7
8  11
9  13
```